# RUN powershell failing in docker build on windows 2019 server

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I am running on Windows 2019 server.

I am getting an error whenever I invoke powershell from a dockerfile on docker build
Error is..

---> Running in 6efa29aa8a4a
The command 'powershell -Command DIR' returned a non-zero code: 3221226505

Dockerfile..

```
# escape=` (backtick)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
RUN DIR

RUN ["powershell", "-Command", "DIR"]

COPY ./ app/
WORKDIR app
CMD [ "someapp", "somearg" ]
```

I have tried replacing cmd with powershell via

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN DIR
```

and the results are the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running a dockerfile more like

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
>
> RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot*
>
> WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
>
> COPY . /inetpub/wwwroot

maybe you gotta move your COPY command after the WORKDIR ?
Try different things out

Comment: Step 2/14 : RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot*
 ---> Running in 6fa7906080d4
The command 'cmd /S /C powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot*' returned a non-zero code: 3221226505

Comment: What I am confused by is all powershell commands fail.. the directory command (RUN DIR) works, but not when invoked by powershell..

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have update KB4532691 installed on your build machine (and host). The newest image of ltsc2019 (20/2020) has issues without it.

See https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t for more info

Comment: Sorry.. my initial post did not mention I am seeing this behavior on windows server 2019., those appear to be windows 10 KB numbers.  According to sysadmin the server is fully patched.

Comment: This is for windows server 2019. see :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t

Comment: We had issues with our build servers and dev hosts when they all got the new images around 2/18. Took a few days of chasing my tail before I found this article, updated our servers and everything went back to working. I just don't want anyone else to waste days looking for issues that don't exist.

Comment: Thanks.. Looks like we have a mismatch..
C:\911web>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1075]

PS C:\911web> docker pull  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.17763.1075
Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.17763.1075 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown


https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore does not list a server for our current server version..

Comment: I think you should be fine using 10.0.17763.1040 or the ltsc2019 tag. Are you able to run `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 powershell` get into a running container and execute a PowerShell command, or does the container not even start up?

Comment: the docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 powershell command did not give any errors.  Just returns back to the prompt after a second or tow.

Comment: @MikeRiddle that means the container won't start with a powershell command. are you able to enter the container using `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`?

Comment: By the way, thanks for the help.. 
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 brings up a command line, but never accepts input and exits after 10 seconds or so

Comment: np, I think what you probably want to do to at this point, is delete that image `docker image rm mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` and pull it again. `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` if you still can't open a container with that image you'll have to look into you're event logs for docker to see if it is having the problem.